# How to make this layout in Android XML

Tags: android, layout, scrollbar, center

I am novice in Android trying to make this layout:
[image: Illustration]

Simply what I want to achieve:
The red container should take as much space as it needs but not as much that green container have to be shrinked. If there are too many items, red container will be scrollable. Green container is also always centered in orange one if there is space for it (if not it is actually still centered).

I don't know how to do it at all :( . Here is my try:

The problem is that I want to always maintain height of green container (minHeight does not work I can't understand why) and make the green container centered in orange one. I have problem with Scenario 2 (as you can see in the picture), this code works good in first scenario.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/red_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- Items are here -->

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/orange_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/green_container"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <!-- My content -->

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Edit: minHeight does not help:**
[image: Proof that minHeight does not work]

**Edit: image for user Illegal Argument:**

[image]

Comment: Do you need to support 2.3 android version?

Comment: this can be easily achieved using relative layout

Comment: What are your "items" in your red view?

Comment: @Fox in socks : I don't need 2.3 support. 4.0+

Comment: @Squonk : LinearLayouts but theoretically it can be whatever

Comment: @Illegal Argument : Can you show me how ? I don't think so.

Comment: @AmancioErnie see my answer let me know if it works for you

Comment: @Illegal Argument it doesn't work, please check my edited post and answer and let me know if it is understandable. I wonder if it is solvable through TableLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting property android:minHeight = "(whatever)dp" to orangeContainer. This worked for me in others "similiar" cases.

:)

Comment: That does not work for me. I've added proof into my post, please check it.

Comment: I would try changing your top LinearLayout to a RelativeLayout, and use android:layout_below="xxx" to place components. Do you know what I mean?. Eventhough, 50dp of minHeight is a very little one. Please, check with 200dp, for example, to get a proof.

Comment: Does not work. I tried it million times. I would really appreciate if you give a sample code. And sorry for small images, I will upload better images next time :) .

Comment: I've been working on this for a "long time", but I'm afraid I'll not find a solution following this way. The problem is that orange and red containers need a reference to each other, and this reference does not exist until the XML parser (the renderer of the XML) detect it. This is why you can make a reference to an upper declared element, but not to one below. I'd recommend you trying with ListViews (as your red container). I think that would be easier. Sorry for not being able to help you better. :(

Comment: Anyway thanks a lot for your time ;) . I rather changed my design little bit. I think it is interesting problem since it is quite simple but it seem like unsolvable.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/list_items"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/list_items"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:minHeight="200dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Snapshot in ecllipse:
[image]

Comment: Thanks but it is not what I want at all. If there is empty upper (red, in your case black) container orange (in your case grey) container should take all the space. And in case that red (in your case black) container has a lot if items there should not be space vertically in orange container (in your case grey) but content of orange container has to be whole visible. Look at the sample I drew in my post.

Comment: I've added image with description in my post for you.